# Can Kepler.gl be used with Angular?

Tags: angular, kepler.gl

I've tried to find a solution of using kepler.gl in Angular but have not had the luck of finding one that works. I'm curious if anyone can link me to a working demo/example. I found this: [Can Kepler.gl be used with Angular.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66951453/can-kepler-gl-be-used-with-angular-js) and I know the question asks for angular js but the answer is given in angular. Not that it matters because it doesn't work anyway.

[Can Kepler.gl be used with Angular.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66951453/can-kepler-gl-be-used-with-angular-js)